# Scrolling down a page in python

Tags: python

Is there a way for me to scroll down a page on python. I have made a timer but I find myself having to scroll down to see how many seconds left. Is there a way for the program to do this for me? Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a way but first read [ask].

Comment: Hi! I would want see your code your code and please explain a little more about what your code does, i.e., what is it programmed to do.

Comment: In this case it might actually make sense to get a screenshot to understand what you mean by "scroll down in python". I take it that you want to scroll to the bottom of a code but that will depend on what you're using to view your code. This is called an IDE (integrated development environment)